# string index out of range/ invalide syntex

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

I got an error as "string index out of range" on running code in the command line while it gives the " invalid syntax" as the error in VS code terminal here is my code

```
def copy(lst1, lst2 = []):
    if lst1==[]:
        return lst2
    else:
        lst2.append(lst1[0])
        copy(lst1[1:],lst2)                       #recursively calling of copy function

    return lst2
def main():
    lst1= input("Enter the string >> ")
    lst2 = copy(lst1)                             #calling of copy function
    print("The copied list is ", lst2)
main()                                            #calling of main function
```

Answer (score 0):

lst1 is a string and lst2 is a list.  The terminating condition of the recursion checks lst1 against an empty list.  But an empty list is not the same as an empty string, so the terminating condition check doesn't work.

```
>>> "" == []
False
```